# Why can't my devices find each other using this Game Kit connection code?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, gamekit

I'm trying to connect two devices over Bluetooth using Game Kit.  The first device is running an application with the following code inside it:

```
-(void)connect
{
    GKPeerPickerController*     picker;

    picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    //picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
    picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
    [picker show];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    peerStatus = kServer;
    gamePacketNumber = 0;
    currentSession = nil;
    gamePeerId = nil;


    NSString *uid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];

    gameUniqueID = [uid hash];
    [self connect]; 

}

- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didSelectConnectionType:(GKPeerPickerConnectionType)type {
    // GKSessionModeClient
   // GKSessionModeServer
    [self.currentSession initWithSessionID:kTankSessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
    currentSession.available = YES;
    currentSession.delegate = self;

}

- (void)peerPickerController:(GKPeerPickerController *)picker didConnectPeer:(NSString *)peerID toSession:(GKSession *)session
{
     self.gamePeerId= peerID;
    //self.currentSession = session;

    self.currentSession.delegate = self;
    [self.currentSession setDataReceiveHandler: self withContext:nil];

    // Remove the picker.
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker dismiss];
    [picker autorelease];
    // Start your game
}

- (void)peerPickerControllerDidCancel: (GKPeerPickerController *)picker
{
      NSLog(@"peerPickerControllerDidCancel");
    picker.delegate = nil;
    [picker autorelease];

}


- (void)session: (GKSession*)session peer:(NSString*)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state
{
     NSLog(@"finding and connecting to others sessions");
    if(state    == GKPeerStateAvailable){
        NSLog(@"aviable and ready to conect");
        [session connectToPeer:peerID withTimeout:60];
        session.available =NO; //put YES si volem multiconexions sino es tancarà la sesio en conectarse 2
    }
}

- (void)session:(GKSession *)session didReceiveConnectionRequestFromPeer:(NSString *)peerID{
     NSLog(@"lisetn for others sessions");
    NSError *error=nil;
    if(amAcceptingConnetions){
        if(![session acceptConnectionFromPeer:peerID error:&error]){
            //Handler error
        }
    }else{
        [session denyConnectionFromPeer:peerID];
    }

}
```

The second device is running another application that uses the same code as above, only with the following piece changed:

```
[self.currentSession initWithSessionID:kTankSessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeServer];
```

The normal window appears on both to indicate that they are searching for other devices, but the two devices don't recognize each other.  What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate currentSession if it's not already being allocated. Perhaps try changing:

```
[self.currentSession initWithSessionID:kTankSessionID displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
```

To this:

```
self.currentSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:kTankSessionID displayName:nil sesssionMode:GKSessionModeClient];
```

You may want to also add a check to see if the session is already allocated, and release it if it is before you create a new one.  I noticed some improvements in performance and reliability if you reset the session every time your devices try to connect, instead of reusing the same session.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import PeerPickerController along with GameKit/Gamekit.h also. If you want to know more,Please refer [this link](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1).

or

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502/0/page/1